# fault in defining numpy array as tensorflow variable

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a x numpy array:

```
[0, 6, 3513, 7, 155, 794, 25, 223, 8, 32, 20, 202, 5025, 350, 91, 6, 66, 207, 5, 2]
```

I want to define it as a tensorflow variable as the following:

```
tf.Variable(x)
```

And I get the following error:

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [0, 6, 3513, 7, 155,
>   794, 25, 223, 8, 32, 20, 202, 5025, 350, 91, 6, 66, 207, 5, 2]

What the hell?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question. Just confirming that import numpy as np; 
import tensorflow as tf; 

x = np.array([0, 6, 3513, 7, 155, 794, 25, 223, 8, 32, 20, 202, 5025, 350, 91, 6, 66, 207, 5, 2]);

tf.Variable(x) works here(as you guessed it should)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share what are you trying to do, as tensorflow just defines a variable you can only use that variable when you are executing that session.
Hope Below code helps you.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np 
    x =[0, 6, 3513, 7, 155, 794, 25, 223, 8, 32, 20, 202, 5025, 350, 91, 6, 
        66, 207, 5, 2]

    # convert it into numpy array 
    w = np.array(x)

    # this create a tensor variable 
    q = tf.Variable(x)

    # create an interactive session 
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


    # now you can perform operation on that tensor variable 

     tf.add(q,q)
```

Comment: First of all, my x array is already a numpy type. Secondly, it didn't work out.

Comment: what didn't work out, can you explain what are you trying to do. Please Share what are you trying to do.

Comment: There is a numpy array, and I am trying to convert it to a tensorflow variable. thats it.

Comment: Have you tried above approach. Sorry, it is difficult for me to help if you don't share your code or approach ".

Comment: I have tried the above approach. There is nothing to share. I just have a damn numpy array, which is int type. I just need to convert it to a damn tensorflow tensor variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.array(...)

v = tf.Variable(tf.constant(x))
```